# How to get product by url_key and store id magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-key

I am working in magento 2 project.

I need to load product collection by url_key and specific store id. I tried but I am getting issue in store id. I search in stack but didn't get solution.

**My Query :**

```
$url = $store->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$url_path_parts = array_filter(explode('/', $url_path));
$currenturl = $url_path_parts[1];
$oRewrite = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->getCollection();
$oRewrite->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', $currenturl, 'left');
$oRewrite->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');
$oRewrite->addStoreFilter(0); // I tried to set store id but not worked
```

If I print query of above query I am getting following query:

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_url_key.value_id > 0, at_url_key.value, at_url_key_default.value) AS `url_key` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_url_key_default` ON (`at_url_key_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_url_key_default`.`attribute_id` = '119') AND `at_url_key_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_url_key` ON (`at_url_key`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_url_key`.`attribute_id` = '119') AND (`at_url_key`.`store_id` = 2) WHERE (IF(at_url_key.value_id > 0, at_url_key.value, at_url_key_default.value) = 'holle-pouchy-apfel-mit-karotte-pastinake-90g')
```

If I add `addAttributeToFilter` then in query I am getting Inner Join with store id 0 and Left join with store id 2.

**I want to get result from store 0. Is it possible to set store id 0 in all   join.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to load any product by filter url key and store id.

```
    $storeid = 1;
    $objectManager     = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $collection        = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

    $productcollection = $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addStoreFilter($storeid)
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute' => 'url_key', 'eq' => 'test112'], // Color filter
            ]
        );

   $productInfo = $productcollection->getData();
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried but not working, As I need to fetch from store id 0. If i write store id 1 then it is working but I need to fetch record from store id 0.

Comment: Please check my mysql query, in inner join store id is already 0, but in left join the store id is 2 that what i want to change. I want to change 2 to 0 in left join

Comment: @DavidCoder if you want to get product from store id 0 then I think no need to mentioned store id there. magento by default will get all records from store id 0(default store) if you don't specify it, please have a look https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135481/55928

Comment: Yes but still it print the same query LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_url_key` ON (`at_url_key`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_url_key`.`attribute_id` = '119') AND (`at_url_key`.`store_id` = 2) here store id is 2.

Comment: store id is coming from $oRewrite->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', $currenturl); default

Answer (score 0):

```
addAttributeToFilter('url_key', $currenturl);   
addStoreFilter($storeId);
```

Comment: I have already tried but not working.